# CSS - Scaling Into Background Image

Tags: html, css

I'm having some issues in scaling into my background image.

The issue is:

- Horizontal and vertical scroll bars appear when the scaling happens. I removed the childDiv, thinking that could be it, but no luck.
  Also tried setting a max-height and max-width however didnt help.

Its almost as if as the image is increasing in width and height, rather than being zoomed into.

My code looks like:

```css
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
  }
}
/* Standard syntax */

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
  }
}
.homeDivParent {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.1)), url("/assets/images/bgHome.jpg");
  background-position: 20% 0%;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  -webkit-animation: zoom 10s;
  animation: zoom 10s;
}
.homeDivChild {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="homeDivParent">
  <div class="homeDivChild">
    Some Text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody - using Chrome

Comment: which version of Chrome?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody - v55.0.2883.95. Its almost as if as the image is increasing in width and height, rather than being zoomed into

Comment: will `box-sizing:border-box` in `homeDivParent` help? combinig with `overflow:hidden`

Comment: well yes, `scale` does scale the width/height. but I'm not seeing the scroll bars in the demo here on SO. do you see scrollbars when you 'Run code snippet'

Comment: @BrettDeWoody I'm seeing bars - when you click run, if you scroll down that section, they'll appear
Other than scale any other ideas i something to try to give the background image some 'movement' I tried background position but its very jittery

Comment: not happening for me. the `homeDivParent` scales up and no scroll bars are ever present.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I unterstand it right, but I think you want to remove the scroll bars, right?

```
.homeDivParent {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: I tried that but the bar still appearing. Its almost as if as the image is increasing in widhth and height, rather than being zoomed into